# Reference to a counter

Tags: counters

Certainly a stupid question. I have a newcounter defined normaly, that is

```
\newcounter{sharc}
```

How can I call a specific value of this counter with a command like label/ref ?

Exemple

```
blabla  `\thesharc`  blala
blabla  `\thesharc`  blabla
blabla  `\thesharc`  blabla <- I want to refer to this value
blabla  `\thesharc`  blabla
```

Comment: To help us help you, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3343/151808)!

You have to use `\refstepcounter` to increase the counter value.

Comment: Use `\refstepcounter{sharc}` followed by `\label{mylabel}` and then `\ref{mylabel}`...

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki Seems the question [Reference an environment counter through label in another counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375206/reference-an-environment-counter-through-label-in-another-counter) referenced by others is about prepending a reference to a specific counter value when printing another counter value. Your question is about creating a reference. As prepending a reference implies creating a reference, one can consider your question a duplicate. Nonetheless in these questions different goals are expressed. Therefore I do not take your question for a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "refer to a value"?

Do you wish to obtain only the plain counter value in arabic numerals even if the counter in question is subordinated to whatsoever other counters and thus `\the<counter>` is defined to prepend whatsoever prefix and apply whatsoever formatting when printing the value?

What about automatic creation of hyperlinks in case of using the hyperref-package?

Be that as it may.

For obtaining only the plain value in arabic numerals of the last counter that was incremented via `\refstepcounter`, Heiko Oberdiek's **zref** package might be of interest.
(Within almost all the sectioning commands of documentclasses for LaTeX, `\refstepcounter` is used for stepping counters. That's because `\refstepcounter` is the macro which makes values of counters available to the `\label`..`\ref`-mechanism.)

For obtaining the expansion of `\the<counter>` without hyperlinks in situations where the **hyperref** bundle/package is in use, Heiko Oberdiek's **refcount** package might be of interest.

(The example below requires to be compiled at least twice/requires at least two LaTeX-runs between which auxiliary files are not deleted.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% --- Layout of MWE.Has nothing to do with
%     referencing-techniques.
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{1.5cm}
\setlength\marginparwidth{\oddsidemargin}
\addtolength\marginparwidth{-2\marginparsep}%
\setlength\topmargin{\oddsidemargin}
\addtolength\textwidth{-1.5\oddsidemargin}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1in}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-\hoffset}
\setlength\evensidemargin{\oddsidemargin}
\setlength\textheight\paperheight
\setlength\footnotesep{.333\topmargin}
\addtolength\textheight{-2\topmargin}
\addtolength\topmargin{-1in}
\addtolength\topmargin{-\voffset}
\setlength\headheight{0ex}
\setlength\headsep{0ex}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0ex
\parskip=.85\ht\strutbox
\topskip=0ex
% --- Layout done. ---

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[counter,user]{zref}
\usepackage{refcount}
\makeatletter
%% This will establish a new zref-property holding just the
%% plain value of the counter that was \refstep'ped as the
%% last one in arabic numerals:
%% (\refstepcounter is used internally by all the 
%%   sectioning-commands of LaTeX-documentclasses.)
\zref@newprop{MyPlainCntValue}{\the\value{\zref@getcurrent{counter}}}%
%
%% This will place both a normal label and a zref-label.
%% The zref-label will store the value of the new property.
%% Both kinds of labels are needed as zref does not yet
%% have hyperref-features.
\newcommand\Mylabel[1]{%
  \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{MyPlainCntValue}%
  \label{#1}%
}%
%
%% This is used for referencing saved MyPlainCntValue-property-values 
%% of zref-labels:
\newcommand\MyPlainCntValueRef[1]{%
   \zref[MyPlainCntValue]{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\newcounter{sharc}[section]
\renewcommand\thesharc{\thesection.\arabic{sharc}}

\begin{document}

\section{Within the preamble define the label-placement- and
         referencing-macros for referencing the plain values
         of counters in arabic numerals.}
\begin{verbatim}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[counter,user]{zref}
\usepackage{refcount}
\makeatletter
%% This will establish a new zref-property holding just the
%% plain value of the counter that was \refstep'ped as the
%% last one in arabic numerals:
%% (\refstepcounter is used internally by all the 
%%   sectioning-commands of LaTeX-documentclasses.)
\zref@newprop{MyPlainCntValue}{\the\value{\zref@getcurrent{counter}}}%
%
%% This will place both a normal label and a zref-label.
%% The zref-label will store the value of the new property.
%% Both kinds of labels are needed as zref does not yet
%% have hyperref-features.
\newcommand\Mylabel[1]{%
  \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{MyPlainCntValue}%
  \label{#1}%
}%
%
%% This is used for referencing saved MyPlainCntValue-property-values 
%% of zref-labels:
\newcommand\MyPlainCntValueRef[1]{%
   \zref[MyPlainCntValue]{#1}%
}%
\makeatother
\end{verbatim}

\section{Define the \texorpdfstring\texttt\empty{sharc}-counter 
         and just for fun bind it to the 
         \texorpdfstring\texttt\empty{section}-counter}
\begin{verbatim}
\newcounter{sharc}[section]
\renewcommand\thesharc{\thesection.\arabic{sharc}}
\end{verbatim}

\section{Within the document-environment step the
         \texorpdfstring\texttt\empty{sharc}-counter via
         \texorpdfstring{\protect\newline}\empty
         \texorpdfstring{\texttt{\string\refstepcounter}}%
         {\textbackslash refstepcounter}, 
         and via 
         \texorpdfstring{\texttt{\string\Mylabel}}%
         {\textbackslash Mylabel}
         place the referencing-labels.}%
(\verb|\refstepcounter| is used internally by all the 
sectioning-commands of \LaTeX-documentclasses.)

\verb|blabla \refstepcounter{sharc}\thesharc\ blabla|:\\
blabla \refstepcounter{sharc}\thesharc\ blabla

\verb|blabla \refstepcounter{sharc}\thesharc\ blabla|:\\
blabla \refstepcounter{sharc}\thesharc\ blabla

\verb|blabla \refstepcounter{sharc}\thesharc\Mylabel{INeedReferenceToThis} blabla|:\\
blabla \refstepcounter{sharc}\thesharc\Mylabel{INeedReferenceToThis} blabla 
\\\emph{(This is to be referenced/linked. Therefore the}
\verb|\Mylabel|\emph{-command was used for placing both a
normal label and a} \textsf{\textbf{zref}}\emph{-label.
For testing the links view the resulting pdf at a
magnification/zoom-factor where scrolling within the window
where the pdf is displayed is needed.)}

\verb|blabla \refstepcounter{sharc}\thesharc\ blabla|:\\
blabla \refstepcounter{sharc}\thesharc\ blabla

\newpage
\section{Referencing the label}%

\verb|\ref{INeedReferenceToThis}| 

yields:

\ref{INeedReferenceToThis}

{(\verb|\ref| comes from the \LaTeXe-kernel but may be 
redefined by some package. This produces the number with all 
prefixes from other counters. When using the 
\textsf{\textbf{hyperref}}-bundle, this also does
produce a hyperlink to the anchor automatically produced by 
\verb|\refstepcounter|.)}

\hrulefill

\verb|\makeatletter|\\
\verb|\getrefbykeydefault{INeedReferenceToThis}%|\\
\verb|                   {}%|\\
\verb|                   {\refused{INeedReferenceToThis}\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}%|\\
\verb|\makeatother|

yields:

\makeatletter
\getrefbykeydefault{INeedReferenceToThis}%
                   {}%
                   {\refused{INeedReferenceToThis}\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}%
\makeatother

{(\verb|\getrefbykeydefault| comes from the 
\textsf{\textbf{refcount}}-package. This produces the number 
with all prefixes from other counters. Even when using the
\textsf{\textbf{hyperref}}-bundle, this does not produce a
hyperlink to the anchor automatically produced by 
\verb|\refstepcounter|.)}

\hrulefill

\verb|\MyPlainCntValueRef{INeedReferenceToThis}|

yields:

\MyPlainCntValueRef{INeedReferenceToThis}

{(\verb|\MyPlainCntValueRef| is defined by
means of macros from the \textsf{\textbf{zref}}-package.
This produces just the plain number in arabic numerals without
any prefixes from other counters. Even when using the 
\textsf{\textbf{hyperref}}-bundle, this does not produce
a hyperlink to the anchor automatically produced by 
\verb|\refstepcounter|.)}

\hrulefill

\verb|\hyperref[INeedReferenceToThis]{\MyPlainCntValueRef{INeedReferenceToThis}}| 

yields:

\hyperref[INeedReferenceToThis]{\MyPlainCntValueRef{INeedReferenceToThis}}

{\sloppy(\verb|\hyperref| comes from the
\textsf{\textbf{hyperref}}-bundle. Therefore this only works
when the \textsf{\textbf{hyperref}}-bundle is loaded.
\verb|\MyPlainCntValueRef| is defined by means of macros 
from the \textsf{\textbf{zref}}-package. This produces just
the plain number in arabic numerals without any prefixes from
other counters. This does also produce a hyperlink to the
anchor automatically produced by 
\verb|\refstepcounter|.)

}
\hrulefill

In expansion contexts you can use \textsf{\textbf{zref}}'s \verb|\zref@extractdefault|
for obtaining just the plain number - here the plain number delivered by 
\verb|\zref@extractdefault| will be used by \verb|\romannumeral| for delivering
roman numerals instead of arabic numerals:

\verb|\makeatletter|\\
\verb|\expandafter\@firstofone|\\
\verb|\expandafter{%|\\
\verb|  \romannumeral|\\
\verb|  \zref@extractdefault{INeedReferenceToThis}%|\\
\verb|                      {MyPlainCntValue}%|\\
\verb|                      {0 \zref@refused{INeedReferenceToThis}\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}%|\\
\verb|}%|\\
\verb|\makeatother|

yields:

\makeatletter
\expandafter\@firstofone
\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral
  \zref@extractdefault{INeedReferenceToThis}%
                      {MyPlainCntValue}%
                      {0 \zref@refused{INeedReferenceToThis}\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}%
}%
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

[image: page 1 of resulting output]
[image: page 2 of resulting output]

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right way,

```
\newcounter{sharc}
```

is the right start. Then you can set it to val (a number, not a counter) with:

```
\setcounter{sharc}{val}
```

If you want to set it to a counter `cnt`, you can use:

```
\setcounter{sharc}{\value{cnt}}
```

To increase it, use:

```
\stepcounter{sharc}
```

In order to reference it, too, please use, as mentioned already in some
comments by NBur and Andrew,

```
\refstepcounter{sharc}
\label{labelname}
```

However, this does not display the counter. So you need to display it by
using one of the following:

```
\arabic{sharc}
\alph{sharc}
\Alph{sharc}
\roman{sharc}
\Roman{sharc}
```

All of these infos you can find in the wikibook [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters).

Combining it all:

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{sharc}
\setcounter{sharc}{2} % set initial value
\renewcommand{\thesharc}{\roman{sharc}} % set references to \roman
\newcommand{\sharcref}[1]{[\ref{#1}]} % reference in brackets

\begin{document}
    initial value: \arabic{sharc} (\Roman{sharc})

    \stepcounter{sharc} % add one
    next value: \arabic{sharc} (\alph{sharc})

    \refstepcounter{sharc} % add one and reference this one
    labeled value: \arabic{sharc} [\roman{sharc}]
    \label{l:sharc}

    this is the label: \ref{l:sharc}\par
    or with the defined command: \sharcref{l:sharc}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning for newbies that in `\setcounter{sharc}{val}`, `val` is a number, not a counter named `val`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik you're right, thanks for mentioning, I edited the answer to include setting it to a counter and clarified that.